# Clean urls and https redirect conflict in .htaccess using YII

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, yii

I have the following in my .htaccess - the clean url's declaration and the https redirect both work fine individually but put together are causing the continuous redirect error (this server is redirecting in a way which will never complete).

Here is my .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
# force to use https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any idea how i can resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you flip the Https / index.php rules do Https is first?

Answer (score 2):

Hope I am not late as I stumbled through your same problem and figured out the conflict just a day ago.

Write the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The first rule will automatically redirect any HTTP requests to HTTPS and (through the crucial `[L]` tag) stop other substitutions which will mess up the page (specifically, images and CSS stylesheets would not be served).

The second one is the Yii suggested way to check whether a particular URL corresponds to a real file or directory and, if not, to forward the request to `index.php` (the bootstrap file for the Web application). (The rules in the application's configuration file should do the rest, then).

Comment: Double check your default-ssl.conf file to ensure that AllowOverride is set to All.  For some reason, one rule worked fine without AllowOverride being set (it wasnt even in the file), but two rules were too many.